# Python matplotlib with percentile data on X axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have probably a simple issue, but I spent more than one hour checking both in here and on google without finding the solution I need.
My simple goal is to plot the histogram for the values stored in a dataframe column.
The problem I face is that I need the x ticks used to define the bins to correspond to percentile values

```
perc = [0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 0.70, 0.90, 1.0]  # percentile values
```

This implies the histogram plot will have non-uniform bin widths.
I tried this solution [Percentiles on X axis with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153054/percentiles-on-x-axis-with-matplotlib) but that gives me ton of vertical bars and not just bins corresponding to my percentile levels.
I also saw a similar question here [python plot hist(graph) with percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827292/python-plot-histgraph-with-percentile) but it doesn't have any answers.

Addition to my question.
I'm trying the following code but it doesn't really do what I need.

```
data = df["sales"].values  # this is a an array with 58k values, 99% of which between 100 and 5000 and 1% of which between 1mln and 2mln
perc = [0, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 0.70, 0.90, 0.99, 1.0] 
perc_values = np.percentile(data, perc)
histaa = np.histogram(data, bins = perc_values)
plt.hist(histaa, bins = perc_values);
```

The bins I obtain has not the same width and the plot has a big empty region.
Adding also a screenshot.
[image]I wonder If anybody could help.
Many thanks

Comment: I wonder what the exact problem is you face. I would guess you need to calculate the percentiles as `numpy.percentile(data, perc)` and use those as bins?

Comment: Sure. I have this dataframe column that has data I need to plot using an histogram. It seems 99% of the blogs show normal distributions and that's not the only distribution in real world. My data for example has 99% of the values falling between the 0 and 99% percentiles. Due to a fat tail, the histogram basically plots one vertical bar for the first 99% values, then there's a massive empty space in the middle of the histogram and finally a super small almost invisible bar at the far right of the plot. Hence, I need to use percentiles data on the x-axis.

Comment: Yeah, so far so good. Did you try using `numpy.percentile(data, perc)`?

Comment: That would give me the percentile values - yes that's ok. but my problem is how to use them as bin delimiters in a histogram plot. Just to be more specific, I would need to have a plot with bins width all with the same size, but bin 1 for example including all the values in data between 0 and first percentile (0.10 in my example), bin 2 containing all the data within percentile 0.10 and 0.20 and so on. I will add to my question the code I'm using that gives me a really messy histogram

Comment: There is an error in your code: You take the already histogrammed values as input to `hist`. This may or may not be relevant to your problem, so I suggest you correct that first. Next, my question would be: How do you imagine unequal binwidth to have equal width on the axis? Do you want to label the bin edges with the percentile numbers?

Comment: Yes, spot on. I imagine each bin label showing the percentile value.

Comment: Ok, so `labels=[234, 567, 678, 1300, 1354], y=[4,5,6,3]; x = list(range(len(labels))); plt.bar(x[:-1], y, align="edge", width=1); plt.xticks(x, labels)`?

Comment: perfect!!!! thank you very much!